# How to highlight empty/blank cells using VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I realized I messed up asking my very first question, so I will try one last time. I am targeting the same 4 columns from 2 separate sheets that have cells that either contain text or do not. Sheet 1 will be updated automatically, so I will be running this code daily to manually update sheet 2. I am trying to find a way to basically find out which cells are missing the text using a macro. I tried using a code that I found on this website that puts borders on cells containing text and clears borders for empty cells.

```
Sub BorderForNonEmpty()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:C252")

' Clear Existing Borders
myRange.Borders.Linestyle = xlLineStyleNone

' Test Each Cell and Put a Border Around it if it has content
For Each myCell in myRange
If myCell.Text <> "" Then
myCell.BorderAround (xlContinuous)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

This code works, but I want to try to highlight the empty cells with a color opposed to clearing its border. This is also my first time posting on StackOverflow, so I apologize beforehand. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looping through all cells, Excel has a built in function to select blank Cells. This should be faster, and more reliable.

```
Sub BorderForNonEmpty()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:C252")

    'clear all color
    myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    'color only blank cells
    myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Another option could be to just use conditional formatting (another built-in feature), but that can be hard to control for changing ranges.

Comment: Glad to help. You've got some good responses here. You should mark one of them as the answer to help other users who may have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
myCell.BorderAround (xlContinuous)
```

with

```
myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub BorderForNonEmpty()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:C252")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If myCell.Text = "" Then
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

```
Sub BorderForNonEmpty()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("C2:C252")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If myCell.Text = "" Then
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

To make the macro "clickable":

1. Put any AutoShape on the worksheet
2. Format the AutoShape
3. Right-click the AutoShape and assign the macro to it.

Comment: Hey Gary's Student. That solved the issue with the highlighting but I was wondering if it were possible to highlight only the empty cells opposed to the cells that have text in them. It is currently highlighting only the cells with text. Thank you for the help.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is run the code to highlight any blank/empty cells that are in a specific column. The purpose of this is to run the code to see if there are any empty cells, so that I can manually update it. The code you wrote highlights only cells with text in it and not the empty cells. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: On my computer, the macro colors **all** empty cells.  It will not color cells containing spaces like   =" "

Comment: I still am not sure to highlight only the empty cells. It keeps highlighting the cells that have values/text. Do you think it would change if I targeted this line:

If myCell.Text = "" Then

Comment: That worked perfectly, Gary's Student. Thank you for your help. Is there a way to create a button for this opposed to pressing F8 -> Run?